# CentOS 7.2 andhivex

Tags: yum, centos7

I need to install libguestfs on a CentOS/RHEL 7.2 server, and I ran into a snag in the dependency chain. When I try to yum localinstall hivex-1.3.10-5.7.el7.x86_64.rpm, it finds a dependency on "perl(Win::Hivex)" which, according to rpmfind.net, should be satisfied by perl-hivex-1.3.10-5.7.el7.x86_64.rpm (OpenSuSE distros satisfy the dependency with perl-Win-Hivex instead)...But the perl-hivex package depends on hivex!

How do I break out of this vicious cycle?

Comment: Are you using RHEL or CentOS? Why are you trying to install local copies of RPMs? And why on earth are you using rpmfind.net? Stay away from that crap if you value your systems.

Comment: It's a CentOS, but that shouldn't matter as the differences between RHEL and CentOS are extremely small.  I have to install local rpms because the system is quarantined.  I used rpmfind.net as a last recourse when I could not locate (in our package database) a package likely to supply "perl(Win::Hivex)".

Comment: Sometimes it does matter between CentOS and RHEL. Your question was too ambiguous to determine whether it did in your case or not, which is why I asked. Anyway, that's a circular dependency all right. Did you try the obvious?

Comment: Probably not, or I wouldn't be asking. (Assuming it resolves the issue)

Comment: Hmm. The obvious is installing both packages at the same time. Apparently not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Hampton suggested (and also independently suggested by [this other thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178768/installing-rpm-packages-with-circular-dependency)), passing both rpms to yum localinstall was the solution. Obvious in retrospect.